# Splitting and flushing equations inside align

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, arrays, split

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    &f = \text{here goes a very very very very very long equation} \nonumber
    \\
    &\hspace*{7.5cm} + \text{which will be split} \label{a}
    \\ 
    &xxx = \text{here goes another super long long equation} \nonumber
    \\
    &\hspace*{5cm} + \text{which continues on the second line} \label{b}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I need to manually align the two equations such that

- The first line of each is flushed left.
- The second line is flushed right and just next to its label (in the example, I use `\hspace*{}`). It does not have to be flushed wrt the above line.
- I can still align the two equations (in the example, the `=` are not aligned).
- These are still two separate equations, so I can assign labels.

I tried with `split` + `equation` and `align` + `aligned`, but then I cannot assign multiple labels. I also tried with `split` inside `align` but then I cannot align the `=`.

Many thanks.

Comment: To have the equations flushed left, use `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two distinct alignment points for the split equation, for the top row aligning with the left-hand side and the equation number aligning with the bottom row.

You can center the equation number, though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\label{a}
f   &=\begin{aligned}[t]
      \text{here goes a very very very very very long equation}
      \\
      {} + \text{which will be split}
      \end{aligned}
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
\label{b}
xxx &=\begin{aligned}[t]
      \text{here goes another super long long equation}
      \\
      {} + \text{which continues on the second line}
      \end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Honestly, this kind of alignment doesn't appeal to me at all.

You can get your desired alignment with `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\newcommand{\meqbox}[2]{\eqmakebox[#1][r]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f ={}& \meqbox{A}{\text{here goes a very very very very very long equation}} \notag
\\
     & \meqbox{A}{{} + \text{which will be split}} \label{a}
\\
xxx ={}& \meqbox{B}{\text{here goes another super long long equation}} \notag
\\
       & \meqbox{B}{{} + \text{which continues on the second line}} \label{b}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Each block should be assigned a distinctive key, here `A` and `B`. Go on with the alphabet if you need other similar objects.

[image]

An even worse realization, notwithstanding it seems what you'd like to get:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
f &= \mathrlap{\text{here goes a very very very very very long equation}} && \notag
\\
&    &&&{} + \text{which will be split} \label{a}
\\
xxx &= \mathrlap{\text{here goes another super long long equation}} && \notag
\\
&    &&&{} + \text{which continues on the second line}  \label{b}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have the second line of each equation completely flushed to the right, ending close to (1) and (2), not aligned with the above line (that's why I use `hspace` in my example, but I would like to get rid of it). I will make the question clearer.

Comment: @Simon Does the last version reflect the horrible thing you want to do? `;-)`

Comment: Ahaha yes, thanks! I know it is a bit ugly, but I believe that the equation I have to split looks better this way than otherwise :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `fleqn`, drop the `\hspace`s and also set the alignment point to the equality sign to get

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    f ={}& \text{here goes a very very very very very long equation} \nonumber
    \\
    &+ \text{which will be split} \label{a}
    \\ 
    xxx ={}& \text{here goes another super long long equation} \nonumber
    \\
    & + \text{which continues on the second line} \label{b}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<s>You may increase the space between the `=` signs and `\text`s.</s> solved by @egreg's comment.

Comment: `={}&` or the space is very wrong.

Comment: @egreg Mille grazie!

Comment: Thanks, I know `fleqn`, but it flushes all equations the same. In my case, I need the first line to be flushed left, and the second to be flushed left (as much as possible, just next to the label number).